# How do I use Index and Small in excel sheet

Tags: excel, indexing, formula, unique

I have three sheets in excel one is supplier sheet and other two sheets are customer sheet. I want that when I update the supplier sheet so the data automatically copy to customer sheet as well. For this I am using this formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(USMANGLOBALKARACHI!$A$8:$A$11, SMALL(IF(USMANGLOBALKARACHI!$C$8:$C$11="BURUNDI", ROW(USMANGLOBALKARACHI!$A$8:$A$11)-MIN(ROW(USMANGLOBALKARACHI!$A$8:$A$11))+1), ROW(C1))), "")
```

The problem is when I copy this formula to the entire sheet so it give me empty cell so where I am wrong. kindly guide me

[image]

[image]

For the clarity I also attached the image of excel sheet. Supplier Name is USMANGLOBALKARACHI and customer name is BURUNDI.

Comment: Hi @Adbul Wahab! Welcome to StackOverflow. First off, I would advise against posting company info in Excel spreadsheets for the internet to see. It isn't best practice even if it isn't very detailed info. Second, I'd suggest formatting your question so that we can read it better. Perhaps also provide a data set so that we can replicate the problem you've got. Help us help you!

Comment: Acknowledge @Ars_Codicis

Comment: This may be helpful to post some sample data (make it dummy data): https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: Not sure what is your excel version, but if you are using an older version, then your formula needs to hit `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` while exiting the edit mode. And its better to use `AGGREGATE()` --> `=IFERROR(INDEX(USMANGLOBALKARACHI!$A$8:$A$11, AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(USMANGLOBALKARACHI!$A$8:$A$11)-(ROW(USMANGLOBALKARACHI!$A$8)+1)/(USMANGLOBALKARACHI!$C$8:$C$11="BURUNDI"),ROW(A1))), "")`

Comment: @ Mayukh Bhattacharya Thank you for your reply but it gives error. kindly make it correct.